# getting value of column in spreadsheet

Tags: devexpress, spreadsheet

I am using `devexpress` and when I try to  get value of a spreadsheet's cell using below code:

```
  Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
  Column firstColumn_byName = columns["A"];
```

I get the following **error**:

> the name columns does not exist in the current context

Comment: what is `columns` here?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined `columns`.

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();

// Access a collection of columns.
ColumnCollection columns = workbook.Worksheets[0].Columns;

// Access the first column by its unique name.
Column firstColumn_byName = columns["A"];
```

Taken from: [devexpress documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#DocumentServer/CustomDocument12086)